# Submitting a large form using jQuery ajax, without using serialize()

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, serialization

I want to submit a large form using jQuery Ajax, but after searching for a solution all day it doesn't appear to be possible.  I hope I'm wrong.

Based on all the numerous threads on this topic, this is what I've got so far.

```
    function familyUpdate() {
      familyOverlay(true);
      var form = $("#familyform");
      var formdata = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'family-update.php',
        data: {
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formdata
        },
        success: function () {
            familyOverlay(false);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Unable to update family");
            familyOverlay(false);
        }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that my form is really big, and as far as I understand it, using serialize() generates a string to submit and essentially converts my POST into a GET which means I am running into the URI length limit of my browser, and as a result the entire form is not submitted.

Is there a way to submit my form using POST, without using serialize() so that I don't have to worry about the length of the data?

Comment: First of all, all data is transfered as strings, and the POST request is not converted to a GET request, they both send strings. The limit of a POST request is really just a server setting, but setting it too high can cause issues with ddos attacks being easier to perform against your server.

Comment: In other words, using `serialize()` makes no difference, and you'd have to have a heck of a form before size limit is an issue, and even then you can increase the limit in most serverside languages, even to 2 gigabytes if you want to, there is no set limit in the spec for POST, however GET requests have a max limit of the length of the URL, and I think it's 2048 bytes ?

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize POST also sends strings.  So what I'm hearing is if my server can handle posting this form the traditional way, then it can handle posting it the ajax way.  My problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes .................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem was with my syntax.

Specifically this part:

```
data: {
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formdata
    },
```

Should've just been...

```
    data: formdata,
    type: 'POST',
```

So this works:

```
function familyUpdate(){
  familyOverlay(true);
  var form = $("#familyform");
  var formdata = form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'family-update.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    success: function() {
      familyOverlay(false);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Unable to update family");
      familyOverlay(false);
    }
  });
}
```

sigh.  It's always the silliest mistakes that waste the most of my time.

Comment: No need to make the two assignments. `data: $("#familyform").serialize(),` is cleaner.

Comment: I actually ended up changing it to var formdata = $("#familyform").serialize();  And still assigning formdata to data.  That's pretty clean to me.  I really only had the "var form" part in there temporarily for testing to make sure I had actually gotten a handle to the form.